# why workflow rule isnt working at salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, workflow

I am quite new to salesforce
There is a field called "Hard Construction Cost" which is Currency type value.
Then there is another fields called "Hard Construction Cost per sqft" which is Currency type and "Max GBA" which is a number type

The field "Hard Construction Cost" needs to be updated like this : max GBA * "Hard Construction Cost"
but the workflow rule isnt work..

any idea why??

Comment: Are you trying to update existing records? Have you tested it with a new record? Is the WF rule activated? Can you post screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

If that field doesn't require user input and is only calculated field then instead of workflow you can use formula field.

Create a formula field with name `Hard Construction Cost`

your formula will be
`Hard_Construction_Cost_per_sqft__c * max_GBA__c`